# Why can't cat the file?

Tags: files, permissions

I have added debian8 into group www-data with command .

```
sudo usermod -G www-data  debian8
```

It can be verified with command.

```
cat /etc/group |grep 'www-data'
www-data:x:33:debian8
```

The ownership properties:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 418 Sep 25  2013 /var/www/html/wp/index.php

sudo ls  -al  /var/www/html/wp
total 200
drwxrwxr--  5 www-data www-data  4096 Jan  5 10:16 .
drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data www-data  4096 Jan  4 15:51 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   418 Sep 25  2013 index.php
```

Why debian8 as a member of group www-data can't cat it?

```
debian8@hwy:/var/www/html/wp$ cat index.php
cat: index.php: Permission denied

sudo getfacl /var/www/html/wp/index.php
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/www/html/wp/index.php
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

Do as heemayl say,**Logout and then login**,the file `/var/www/html/wp/index.php` can be cated,why can't touch a new file in `/var/www/html/wp/test.txt` now?

```
touch  /var/www/html/wp/test.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘/var/www/html/wp/test.txt’: Permission denied
```

[image]

It is so strange that

no problem for

```
touch  /var/www/html/wp/test1.txt
```

no permission  for

```
touch  /var/www/html/wp/test.txt
```

Comment: what is the persmission of wp and html folder ? is it having read permission for group and others ?

Comment: Logout and then login.

Comment: @Kamaraj:  The permissions are in the question (`/var/www/html`: `drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data www-data` and `/var/www/html/wp`: `drwxrwxr--  5 www-data www-data`).

Comment: @Theophrastus:  The prank idea is funny but the problem is probably that they just didn't logout and log back in.  We may never know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a crucial point that touch needs write access so in case of `touch test.txt` which have permission -rw-r--r-- which allows you to read and not modify. so write permission is missing for group if you do `chmod g+w test.txt` it will work fine. And you figured out that you need to re-login to see effect of changes made to system parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to reproduce your issue, the point is that you already have created such file "*test.txt*" in your folder with owner and group '*www-data*', so as you are trying to create with `touch` a file that already exists and you are not the owner, you have "Permission denied", however you can read that file with `cat` because the file has read permissions for other users.